# How can I capture traffic made from IIS on localhost using Fiddler

Tags: iis

I have a Web project which runs inside IIS on a localhost. I want to capture traffic made in my web project in IIS.

My web site need to query data from an external source (not in localhost). I want to capture the traffic between my website run on localhost to this external source) using fiddler.

I read this page:
https://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2015/02/19/capture-iis-network-traffic-in-fiddler/

But I can't find where is my web.conf file. I search my whole drive. 
Can you please tell me where is web.config so that I can make the suggested change?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify what you're actually trying to accomplish and *who* will be accessing your web server *from where*. Or is it perhaps that *your web site is accessing* something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a Web Project with Visual Studio, the file is in the project’s root directory, next to the `.csproj` file:

[image: web.config location]

When you publish your project on IIS, the file is, again, in the Application’s root directory. This is guaranteed because IIS also uses `web.config` files to store its per-directory configuration.

`web.config` files are also neither hidden nor protected system files.

Comment: Thanks. But I have search in the directory in my *.csproj, there is no web.config in the directory. I only see packages.config file.

Comment: That’s unusual. I suggest you recreate your project from scratch and then, after verifying the `web.config` file exists, copy your stuff over. Otherwise, there should also be an entry for `web.config` in the “Add File” dialog. You’ll have to wait til Monday if you want a screenshot of that, though.